# Как проверить что ssh server стоит в автозагрузке?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Как проверить что ssh server стоит в автозагрузке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[root@mailcenter ldap]# chkconfig --list sshd
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

как видим, на 2-5 уровнях в автостарте..

Comment: а как так получилось, что в ubuntu есть chkconfig?

Comment: А почему нет? 

    bdstore@bdstore:~$ uname -a
    Linux bdstore 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    bdstore@bdstore:~$ whereis chkconfig
    chkconfig: /sbin/chkconfig /usr/share/man/man8/chkconfig.8.gz

Comment: круть )) у меня правда его нет, и я думал, что это чисто rpm-бэйзд инструмент. оказывается можно поставить.
а cat /etc/issue можно глянуть?

Comment: пожалуйста

    bdstore@bdstore:~$ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

ну если у вас нет chkconfig, глядите так

    bdstore@bdstore:~$ grep Default-Start /etc/init.d/ssh
    # Default-Start:        2 3 4 5

Comment: ага, работает )

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы посмотреть состояние, выполните `sudo reboot` , а после перезагрузки машины -

```
sudo service ssh status
```